# How to properly use the same coil of an HERMS setup as chiller?

Tags: techniques, chilling, wort-chiller, chiller

I'm assembling an HERMS equipment and noticed that very few people use the coil as chiller after the boiling is over. Besides all the sanitation of tubing, lines, pump, etc..., is there any other drawbacks?

**EDIT**: The coil will be permanently attached to the kettle and brewing two batches in a single day is never going to happen. I have no space to ferment two beers at the same time.

Comment: How are you assembling it? If you're just dropping the coil into hot water for its HERMS function, then there's no reason you couldn't dump it into hot wort with cold water running through it to chill. If, on the other hand, you're mounting the coil permanently into the hot water bath for the HERMS, then you're going to have a hard time chilling with it. Additionally, if you use the one coil for both purposes, you could never chill and mash at the same time (in the event that you brewed twice in one day).

Comment: @Frazbro: looks like a nice answer, why post it as a comment?

Comment: @chthon Haha, when I started I was just trying to get more info, then I got distracted. I'll shift it over

Comment: @Frazbro: Edited the question answering you answers. I did not understand why am I going to have a hard time chilling with it. After sparge, I could drain all hot water from the HLT, sanitize everything, fill it with cold water and after the boil is over, pump the wort through the coil. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you fill the hlt with ice water, that could be quite effective. I would recommend giving it a trial run with the coil not permanently mounted first, just to make sure it will perform as you hope. The cooling efficiency will ultimately come down to the size and nature of the coil, and how effectively it can dump heat into the cold water. Agitation of the cold water will help, as will anything that can keep the temperature of the cold water down - the more heat it takes from the wort, the less effective it becomes as a coolant. I theory though, there's nothing wrong with your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you assembling it? If you're just dropping the coil into hot water for its HERMS function, then there's no reason you couldn't dump it into hot wort with cold water running through it to chill. If, on the other hand, you're mounting the coil permanently into the hot water bath for the HERMS, then you're going to have a hard time chilling with it. Additionally, if you use the one coil for both purposes, you could never chill and mash at the same time (in the event that you brewed twice in one day).